# Plotting categorical data counts over time

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a DataFrame (`df`) with a column containing categorical data (`ETH`), with a DateTimeIndex, and I'd like to plot the category *counts* over time (they're indexed by day, and I'd ideally like to plot them by year).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'County': {
        0: 'Bexar',
        3: 'Nueces',
        4: 'Kerr',
        9: 'Harris',
        13: 'Hidalgo'},
    'Date': {
        0: '2012-10-28 00:00:00',
        3: '2012-04-16 00:00:00',
        4: '2013-09-04 00:00:00',
        9: '2013-01-22 00:00:00',
        13: '2013-09-26 00:00:00'},
    'ETH': {
        0: 'Red',
        3: 'Green',
        4: 'Red',
        9: 'Green',
        13: 'Red'}
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format = True)
df['ETH'] = df['ETH'].astype('category')
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

However, no combination of groupby or pivot is giving me anything remotely like what I want, even though I know this should be fairly simple. I can't seem to find a standard approach to do this – help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will groupby the category 'ETH' first and then iterate over each of the groups.

For each of the groups it then groups by the DataTimeIndex year using a lambda function, and returns the count of rows in that year. It then plots these counts.

When plotting the year, it plots it as a number (not a date) which is why the x-axis looks a bit strange, you could probably convert it back to a date (say 1st Jan for each year) to make it prettier. I've adjusted the limits a bit using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` to make it easier to see.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'County': {
        0: 'Bexar',
        3: 'Nueces',
        4: 'Kerr',
        9: 'Harris',
        13: 'Hidalgo'},
    'Date': {
        0: '2012-10-28 00:00:00',
        3: '2012-04-16 00:00:00',
        4: '2013-09-04 00:00:00',
        9: '2013-01-22 00:00:00',
        13: '2013-09-26 00:00:00'},
    'ETH': {
        0: 'Red',
        3: 'Green',
        4: 'Red',
        9: 'Green',
        13: 'Red'}
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format = True)
df['ETH'] = df['ETH'].astype('category')
df = df.set_index('Date')

grouped = df.groupby('ETH')

for key, group in grouped:
    data = group.groupby(lambda x: x.year).count()
    data['ETH'].plot(label=key)

plt.xlim(2011, 2014)
plt.ylim(0,3)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

*Yes, I realise the colours don't match the ETH variable so that "Green" is plotted in blue and "Red" is plotted in green :P*

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!