# Plotting categorical data over time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have a data set as follows:

```
[Time of notification], [Station], [Category]
2019-02-04 19.36:22, Location A, Alert
2019-02-04 20.06:35, Location B, Request
2019-02-05 07.04:53, Location A, Incident
```

Time of notification is in datetime64[ns] format. The time span is one year.

I am trying to get the following line graphs:

- One per station
- Time on x axis. Preferably: Accumulated for days of the week and hours (e.g. all Mondays, Tuesdays etc together, so that a daily/weekly trend over the whole year becomes visible).
- Number of notifications (for that station) on the y axis. Category is irrelevant.

I have tried a lot, but I am new to time series and to visualization, and I am getting nowhere after hours of trying. I have been trying with `plt.subplots, value_counts` etcetera. Also tried making this graph for one station first, but even that didn't work out.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862214/plotting-categorical-data-counts-over-time/60164809#60164809 , modified that code for my dataset, but keep ketting a Key Error for some reason.