# Idiomatic plotting of categorical data over time

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset is a ledger of online 1v1 games stored in a wide dataframe with many columns. Each row represents a game, including the date and the average rating of both players, bucketized into categorical buckets. I'd like to plot the quarterly count of games at each rating bucket.

I *think* the right approach is to create a frame of ratings indexed by time and `.resample('Q')` to group, like so:

```
>>> df.shape
(492367, 139)
>>> ratings = df[['durations.database.start', 'meta.rating.bucket']]
>>> ratings.columns = 'date', 'bucket'
>>> ratings.set_index('date', inplace=True)
>>> ratings.resample('Q').bucket.value_counts()
date        bucket          
2016-03-31  (300.0, 800.0]      5358
            (800.0, 1300.0]     3586
            (1300.0, 1800.0]    1955
            (-inf, 300.0]       1140
            (1800.0, inf]        121
                                ... 
2021-06-30  (300.0, 800.0]      3492
            (800.0, 1300.0]     1935
            (-inf, 300.0]       1220
            (1300.0, 1800.0]     803
            (1800.0, inf]        353
Name: bucket, Length: 110, dtype: int64
```

This looks pretty good, but now I'd like to pass it into sns.barplot() and I've no idea how to do that idiomatically (e.g., without iterating over the groups, or unpacking the frame to be singly-indexed with date repetitions, etc).

Is this the right approach? If not, how should I go about this?

(NB: I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862214/plotting-categorical-data-counts-over-time), but it's quite old and I *think* there are better ways in modern Pandas)